# How to programmatically add a Qt widget (QPushButton, QTextEdit, QLabel) to a Qt Designer layout?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlayout

Is it possible to dynamically add widgets (PushButtons, Labels, etc.), into a Qt Designer-generated central widget layout? How can it be done?

Thank you!

Comment: One more solution, would be to add elements in QT Designer to layout, and then do ui->label->hide() and use show() method to display when needed. Works very well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, and it's quite easy. You can have a look at the ui_mainwindow.h at the debug/release dir. I prefer setting layouts for widgets in QtDesigner to the code. It's something like this:

```
//set layout programatically
auto layout = new QHBoxLayout(ui->centralWidget());

//or if you have set horizontalLayout in Qt Designer
auto layout = dynamic_cast<QHBoxLayout*>(ui->centralWidget->layout());

layout->addWidget(new QLabel("hello"));
```

Comment: Hey, Both of those dont seem to work, ui->centralWidget does not have an addWidget method.
Also the second line, gives an error "expected ( after dynamic_cast", also once the layout is obtained, how to add widget to it and cause refresh on centralWidget?

Comment: That should work fine now. @AakashThakkar